# Como descodificar um código que modifica as vogais

Tags: java, string

Estou tentando criar um código que modifica as vogais. Como exemplo de uma entrada seria:

```
2n1v5rs0 5 t2d0 0 q25 5x1st5 f1s1c4m5nt5, 1ncl21nd0 t0d0s 0s ...
```

e a saída seria:

> universo e tudo o que existe fisicamente, incluindo todos os ...

Pensei em começar o código com algo desse tipo:

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

if()
    char a = reader.next().charAt(4);
    char e = reader.next().charAt(5);
    char i = reader.next().charAt(1);
    char o = reader.next().charAt(0);
    char u = reader.next().charAt(2);
else
```

Mas não sei o que colocar em `if` e `else`.

Answer (score 0):

Use o metodo `public String replace(char oldChar, char newChar)`

```
import java.io.*;
public class Test {

 public static void main(String args[]) {
   String Str = new String("2n1v5rs0 5 t2d0 0 q25 5x1st5 f1s1c4m5nt5, 1ncl21nd0 t0d0s 0s");

   Str = Str.replace("1", "i");
   Str = Str.replace("2", "u");
   Str = Str.replace("0", "o");
   Str = Str.replace("4", "a");
   Str = Str.replace("5", "e");
   System.out.print(Str);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma alternativa é criar um [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) que mapeia cada caractere que vai ser substituído pela sua respectiva letra, e usar um [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) para fazer as substituições:

```
String texto = "2n1v5rs0 5 t2d0 0 q25 5x1st5 f1s1c4m5nt5, 1ncl21nd0 t0d0s 0s";

Map<Character, Character> trocas = new HashMap<Character, Character>();
trocas.put('4', 'a'); // troca o "4" por "a"
trocas.put('5', 'e'); // troca o "5" por "e"
trocas.put('1', 'i'); // e assim por diante
trocas.put('0', 'o');
trocas.put('2', 'u');

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(texto);
for (int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++) {
    char ch = sb.charAt(i);
    if (trocas.containsKey(ch)) {
        sb.setCharAt(i, trocas.get(ch));
    }
}
String novoTexto = sb.toString();
```

A [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/197719/112052) usa [`replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,char)), que também funciona, mas cada chamada de `replace` cria uma nova `String`. Usando uma instância de `StringBuilder`, eu faço todas as substituições nela e só no final eu gero a nova `String`.

---

Outra alternativa é obter o array de `char`'s da `String` usando [`toCharArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()), fazer as substituições neste array e no final usá-lo para criar a nova `String`:

```
Map<Character, Character> trocas = etc... // igual ao código anterior
char[] charArray = texto.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
    char ch = charArray[i];
    if (trocas.containsKey(ch)) {
        charArray[i] = trocas.get(ch);
    }
}
String novoTexto = new String(charArray);
```

Esta alternativa também evita a criação de várias strings, gerando uma nova apenas no final.