# Estou fazendo um exercico e não sei o motivo de estar dando errado(exericio em print no anexo do post e meu código abaixo),oq esta errado?

Tags: java, array, string

MyIo é usado pelo meu professor pra substituir scanner e etc
as strings que eu vou usar no exercício são grandes e diversas então qualquer exemplo que vcs pensarem serve de base.
é meu primeiro post,me desculpe se ficar fora do padrão!

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.*;

public class Aleatorio {


    public static void alterarString(String in,char firstletra,char secundletra)
    {
        String out = in;

        for(int i = 0;i < alterarString.length(); i++)

        {
            if(in.charAt(i) == firstletra)
            {
                out.charAt(i) == secundletra;
            }
        }
        return out;

    }


    public static boolean theEnd(String s)
    {
        return (s.length() == 3 && s.charAt(0) == 'F' && s.charAt(1) == 'I' && s.charAt(2) == 'M');
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] frase = new String[1000];
        int numString = 0; 
        do {
        
        String[] frase[numString] = MyIo.nextLine(); 
        }
        while(theEnd(frase[numString++]) == false);
        numString--;
       
       
        Random gerador = new Random();
        gerador . setSeed (4);

        char secundletra;
        char firstletra;
        for(int i =0;i<numString; i++)
        {

        char firstletra = (char)('a'+(Math.abs( gerador.nextInt())%26)));
        char secundletra = (char)('a'+(Math.abs( gerador.nextInt())%26)));
        MyIo.println(alterarString (alterarString(frase[i],firstletra,secundletra)));

        }
 }
```

Comment: A variável **alterarString** dentro da função **alterarString** não foi declarada. Um erro de digitação?

Comment: O certo é **import java.util.Random;**, com "R" maiúsculo.

Comment: @AdrianoSiqueira eu que não coloquei mesmo,a variável que eu quero na função alterarString é a String out,eu precisaria declarar uma variável com o mesmo nome da função?

Comment: Não sei se entendi o objetivo do código, mas talvez isso ajude: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/449163/112052

Comment: @Gabriel, o que esse código deveria fazer exatamente?

Comment: -ele tem que recebe uma string e sortear 
duas letras minusculas aleatorias pra dps substituie todas as ocorrencias da
primeira letra na string pela segunda e retorna a string com as alteracoes efetuadas @AdrianoSiqueira

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veja se é isso o que você precisa:

```
package string;

import java.util.Random;

public class Aleatorio {

    public static String alterarString(String string, char primeiraLetra, char segundaLetra) {
        String pesquisa = String.valueOf(primeiraLetra);
        String novo = String.valueOf(segundaLetra);
        return string.replaceAll(pesquisa, novo);
    }

    public static boolean theEnd(String s) {
        return s.equals("FIM");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] frase = new String[1000];
        int posicao = 0;

        do {
            frase[posicao] = MyIo.nextLine();
        } while (!theEnd(frase[posicao++]));
        
        posicao--;

        Random gerador = new Random();
        gerador.setSeed(4);

        char primeiraLetra;
        char segundaLetra;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < posicao; i++) {
            primeiraLetra = (char) ('a' + (Math.abs(gerador.nextInt()) % 26));
            segundaLetra = (char) ('a' + (Math.abs(gerador.nextInt()) % 26));
            MyIo.println(alterarString(frase[i], primeiraLetra, segundaLetra));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ajudou demais!! muito obrigado! como to começando eu ainda erro muito no quesito de escrever o codigo certo,eu ja programava em C ai passou pro java na faculdade e eu não consegui acompanhar,Muito obrigado!